# Coupling arrayfire with boost::odeint

Tags: c++, gpu, ode, thrust, arrayfire

I wrote a function incorporating several calls to 2d-ffts and matrix-vector-multiplications in C++, using `arrayfire`, such that I can run and compile the program both on the CPU and GPU. Reason for that is that my dev. PC does not have a GPU, but my production PC has one.
Now, this function serves as right hand side for an ODE, which I would like to solve. One approach is to use `odeint`, but `odeint` does not (natively) support arrayfire-arrays. Thus, before each step using `odeint` I have to copy the 2d-arrays from arrayfire into a `std::vector<>`, put them into the `odeint`-function and call my function, where I have to transfer the data back into `af::arrays` in that function. After processing the data I have to transfer the data back into vectors, before returning to the ode-solver. This approach seems unnecessarily complex and slow.
Therefore, are there other options I could use for solving this ODE? Based on my experience I would like to run it on the GPU to access the performance advantages for zgemv and 2d-FFT, but am (currently) not able to develop it natively due to the lack of a GPU.
I saw that boost.odeint supports thrust. Would that be another option (which means that I have to rewrite the functions), or are there better solutions?